# Does anyone know how to live stream HD videos from raspberry pi B+ to ubuntu?

Tags: streaming, raspberrypi

Does anyone know how to live stream HD videos from raspberry pi B+ to Ubuntu 14.04.02. Currently am working on my drone project using raspberry pi b+ and Ubuntu. I used SSH and created a connection between them. But the question is i am not really sure how to live stream videos to Ubuntu. I came to know that we can live stream from raspberry pi cam using Motion but i have no idea how Motion works and i got no interest in raspi cam. I am curious if there is any the best and easiest way to try to stream video from my Gopro or Turnigy HD ActionCam 1080P to Ubuntu. Also if you have a good tutorials or software for me about this matter, I would love to use it.

Comment: You may try searching for python-bottle scripting and access server created by that using any connection technique, best will be wifi.

Comment: you may try robotics community on stack exchange for better support for these problems.

Answer (score 0):

This was two scripts that helped us do the live streaming thing on a simple raspberry controlled Robot.

We installed library file, i.e. Python bottle by putting `sudo apt-get install python-bottle`

And then we created 2 files which you can get through [github page for sample codes](https://github.com/moithil/highBot)

Check these codes if it can help you make the interface for the live streaming thing.

I would suggest you asking for these robotics related questions to [robotics forum on stack exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) for better support.